# MySQL server has gone away #2006 - Azure server and using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, azure, adodb

I have trouble with this query:

```
create temporary table IF NOT EXISTS vt_tmp_u2275(id int(11) primary key) ignore (SELECT 2275 as id) UNION (SELECT vt_user2role.userid AS userid FROM vt_user2role INNER JOIN vt_users ON vt_users.id=vt_user2role.userid INNER JOIN vt_role ON vt_role.roleid=vt_user2role.roleid WHERE vt_role.parentrole like 'H1::H4::H43::H401::H249::H250::H251::H776::H252::H544::H687::H794::H253::H360::H441::H442::%') UNION (SELECT groupid FROM vt_groups where groupid in (2841,2842,2843,2844,2845,2846,2847,2848,2864,2897,2903,2904,2908,2909,2910,3325,3372,3374,3377,4255,4379,4402,4541,4548,4740,4791,4792,4803,4805,4912,4953,4964,4966,4969,4970,4973,4982,4984,4985,4995,5004,5009,5010,5011,5017,5018,5023,5026,5033,5034,5041,5042,5043,5045,5047,5048,5050,5051,5055,5060,5062,5064,5065,5066,5072,5074,5078,5080,5086,5088,5099,5116,5130,5211,5213,5252,5293,5298,5300,5305,5309,5310,5313,5327,5331,5333,5343,5363,5364,5373,5415,5418,5420,5423,5424,5438,5448,5451,5453,5468,5491,5492,5513,5544,5601,5606,5611,5744,5905,5938,6023,6031,6032,6033,6034,6035,6038,6041,6042,6046,6056,6064,6065,6069,6070,6072,6079,6091,6092,6100,6101,6105,6113,6129,6153,6154,6155,6156,6158,6162,6164,6165,6166,6167,6171,6172,6173,6175,6177,6178,6183,6190,6201,6203,6204,6205,6207,6210,6212,6218,6219,6221,6225,6231,6248,6258,6259,6261,6264,6265,6266,6267,6268,6269,6270,6271,6274,6275,6276,6277,6279,6280,6281,6282,6293,6298,6311,6312,6313,6314,6315,6317,6319,6320,6323,6324,6325,6327,6328,6329,6330,6334,6355,6364,6391,6392,6394,6395,6399,6400,6404,6405,6407,6408,6409,6411,6412,6415,6424,6428,6430,6431,6432,6433,6435,6436,6443,6447,6449,6864,6867,6868,6869,6875,6880,6883,6884,6885,6942,6954,6959,6961,6966,6967,6969,6972,6978,6980,6981,6987,6989,6992,6994,6997,6998,7001,7003,7006,7007,7012,7013,7017,7022,7030,7031,7037,7038,7041,7044,7045,7046,7048,7052,7056,7057,7067,7070,7078,7079,7088,7090,7092,7093,7096,7100,7101,7102,7103,7108,7109,7115,7116,7117,7119,7120,8215,8525,8528,8725,8739,8927,9161,9162,9258,9259,9296,9331,9459,9460,9499,9504,9505,9563,9569,9570,9571,9669,9671,9700,9730,9754,9788,9859,9936,9957,10089,10196,10197,10673,10764,10781,10798,10805,11552,11553,11618,11627,11697,11807,11822,11824,11825,11826,11837,11838,11840,11841,11878,11903,11904,11920,11921,11922,11962,11964,11982,11984,12020,12021,12022,12032,12052,12053,12069,12104,12105,12113,12134,12141,12142,12144,12145,12175,12176,12184,12190,12206,12207,12208,12217,12246,12248,12249,12273,12303,12320,12325,12357,12374,12394,12409,12422,12438,12455,12511,12518,12632,12638,12671,12700,12752,12756,12757,12758,12763,12766,12772,12775,12780,12799,12800,12801,12812,12828,12833,12836,12837,12854,12884,12896,12900,12902,12930,12931,12992,12993,12994,13021,13028,13029,13035,13086,13095,13139,13162,13173,13182,13183,13196,13197,13207,13209,13213,13214,13268,13269,13297,13298,13302,13322,13323,13324,13337,13340,13342,13355,13357,13359,13380,13404,13405,13406,13407,13420,13421,13422,13423,13428,13429,13430,13432,13435,13449,13450,13451,13459,13460,13461,13462,13463,13466,13481,13482,13572,13611,13612,13626,13627,13643,13658,13659,13665,13683,13691,13692,13693,13699,13700,13701,13720,13721,13722,13728,13729,13743,13757,13758,13759,13761,13770,13771,13803,13809,13810,13812,13813,13814,13816,13845,13864,13865,13883,13884,13885,13886,13887,13893,13894,13895,13896,13913,13914,13962,13981,14038,14048,14050,14057,14058,14066,14068,14070,14076,14077,14092,14094,14099,14104,14126,14147,14152,14159,14167,14168,14176,14177,14178,14189,14190,14195,14196,14202,14204,14231,14238,14239,14240,14241,14243,14270,14271,14272,14292,14293,14303,14306,14318,14319,14320,14328,14337,14338,14340,14341,14342,14343,14374,14375,14376,14380,14384,14385,14389,14394,14406,14407,14412,14416,14417,14418,14419,14420,14421,14422,14423,14424,14425,14426,14427,14428,14429,14430,14431,14432,14433,14434,14435,14436,14437,14438,14439,14440,14441,14442,14443,14444,14445,14446,14448,14449,14450,14451,14452,14454,14455,14456,14462,14463,14465,14466,14467,14469,14479,14489,14492,14493,14494,14495,14496,14497,14499,14500,14503,14505,14507,14508,14514,14515,14519,14522,14525,14526,14527,14528,14542,14543,14547,14549,14553,14558,14559,14562,14608,14609,14615,14626,14627,14628,14632,14634,14638,14642,14667,14675,14684,14687,14691,14704,14705,14708,14711,14742,14747,14748,14759,14760,14761,14766,14767,14840,14841,14849,14858,14868,14869,14876,14879,14881,14882,14904,14907,14911,14912,14917,14918,14928,14953,15016,15050,15056,15060,15062,15073,15074,15081,15083,15086,15088,15092,15095,15101,15109,15110,15111,15140,15141,15142,15143,15144,15146,15149,15150,15166,15167,15176,15193,15194,15195,15199,15209,15220,15221,15223,15228,15247,15248,15249,15250,15251,15268,15269,15270,15271,15272,15273,15275,15278,15305,15320,15324,15365,15366,15388,15389,15390,15405,15415,15416,15430,15431,15432,15433,15436,15453,15454,15455,15461,15472,15473,15474,15480,15481,15500,15501,15520,15521,15522,15547,15557,15558,15559,15560,15561,15569,15576,15577,15578,15579,15589,15590,15591,15592,15593,15594,15607,15608,15615,15616,15617,15618,15623,15624,15625,15627,15628,15650,15662,15663,15682,15688,15689,15690,15717,15720,15721,15722,15723,15724,15732,15734,15735,15758,15772,15786,15788,15800,15801,15802,15803,15804,15805,15817,15818,15819,15839,15840,15863,15864,15865,15883,15884,15885,15886,15897,15907,15915,15917,15918,15937,15938,15949,15951,15958,15959,15960,15973,15975,15976,15983,15984,15985,15986,15988,15996,15997,16007,16008,16009,16015,16016,16029,16037,16045,16046,16047,16053,16062,16063,16072,16074,16075,16076,16077,16085,16089,16095,16115,16116,16120,16123,16127,16129,16130,16131,16135,16136,16154,16155,16158,16159,16160,16166,16167,16173,16174,16175,16176,16177,16178,16179,16180,16192,16193,16200,16210,16211,16213,16214,16215,16216,16217,16237,16238,16239,16240,16247,16254,16255,16276,16277,16278,16286,16294,16296,16299,16313,16317,16337,16344,16372,16386,16389,16390,16391,16415,16441,16446,16458,16467,16468,16469,16470,16474,16489,16490,16491,16507,16508,16509,16522,16523,16524,16525,16526,16527,16529,16559,16641,16642,16645,16646,16647,16648,16649,16650,16652,16653,16669,16671,16678,16679,16680,16683,16694,16695,16697,16698,16702,16709,16710,16711,16712,16713,16729,16730,16731,16732,16745,16746,16747,16761,16762,16766,16841,16862,16865,16878,16893,16904,16905,16906,16907,16930,16931,16932,16946,16947,16960,16961,16964,16992,17003,17004,17014,17015,17021,17022,17023,17041,17048,17049,17050,17051,17058,17059,17073,17092,17112,17120,17124,17134,17135,17136,17138,17139,17160,17172,17175,17181,17182,17186,17187,17196,17198,17200,17210,17230,17244,17246,17249,17261,17264,17265,17279,17286,17309,17314,17326,17327,17328,17333,17334,17335,17339,17349,17350,17351,17352,17353,17355,17371,17373,17376,17377,17397,17398,17399,17406,17407,17408,17412,17424,17426,17427,17437,17438,17449,17450,17451,17452,17453,17466,17467,17488,17489,17490,17491,17514,17515,17516,17521,17535,17536,17567,17569,17581,17601,17635,17640,17650,17653,17655,17656,17659,17672,17695,17700,17702,17742,17744,17764,17766,17771,17772,17781,17783,17792,17795,17797,17798,17799,17832,17833,17858,17859,17881,17888,17904,17905,17959,17960,17961,17966,17967,17990,17995,17997,17998,18000,18014,18052,18057,18058,18059,18064,18076,18077,18079,18083,18113,18114,18115,18116,18117,18123,18124,18125,18140,18145,18149,18151,18152,18153,18176,18188,18193,18199,18206,18207,18208,18218,18219,18221,18222,18223,18225,18241,18244,18249,18250,18252,18266,18267,18268,18269,18270,18271,18273,18285,18286,18287,18292,18293,18295,18304,18307,18308,18321,18323,18325,18329,18331,18332,18341,18342,18343,18345,18358,18359,18360,18365,18369,18370,18371,18372,18373,18374,18375,18392,18395,18397,18401,18420,18421,18422,18428,18476,18482,18485,18497,18501,18514,18515,18522,18523,18524,18525,18526,18527,18528,18535,18536,18537,18538,18539,18545,18546,18560,18561,18562,18563,18564,18567,18568,18569,18570,18572,18574,18575,18576,18577,18578,18582,18584,18595,18596,18603,18604,18623,18624,18628,18629,18630,18631,18640,12901,13436,14093,15087,15391,15392,15397,15556,15562,15733,16212,16442,16555,17378,17568,17634,17654,17678,17791,17831,18031)
```

**Error:** MySQL server has gone away
**Code:** 2006

Code is 2006 so I found [online](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gone-away.html) it is *CR_SERVER_GONE_ERROR*. I tried to resolve this issue, but without succession...

Here are some server related settings:

**MySQL 8.0:**

- wait_timeout: 2147483
- innodb_lock_wait_timeout: 1073741824
- lock_wait_timeout: 31536000
- net_read_timeout: 31536000
- net_write_timeout: 31536000
- interactive_timeout: 31536000
- max_allowed_packet: 1073741824
- tmp_table_size: 134217728
- max_join_size: 18446744073709551615

**PHP 7.2:**

- default_socket_timeout: 60000
- mysqli.reconnect: On
- post_max_size: 128000M
- upload_max_filesize: 128000M
- max_execution_time: 60000
- max_input_time: 60000
- memory_limit: 128000M

Values are extremely high for debugging reasons. Hint could be that, when I edit query and remove only one groupid from there, error disappears and everything works as expected.
When I run query in adminer without using application, query passes even without editing.
I am using SSL MySQL connection to Azure MySQL server 8.0.15 / tried also MySQL 5.6, same trouble.
When running this query on local dev environment, app works fine. As a driver for DB connection, I'm using adodb mysqli driver.
I also tried to compare server settings of both MySQL and PHP on local and beta server, it wasn't useful. Now I think trouble could be somewhat around that SSL connection to database. But I don't know what to search for...
Please help, I am out of ideas right now...

---

### UPDATE

So I tried to turn off the SSL enforcing on Beta server in Azure portal and change connection on app - not to use the SSL connection.
App loaded results without error. So yes, problem is related to SSL connection with MySQL server.

Comment: Hi,
have you by any chance found a solution?

Comment: Hello @pavel242, actually yes. I solved this issue by setting indexes on other tables in the database.
They do load after this query in transaction so problem was related to this... Actually I don't know the reason why it worked, it was only coincidence.